# Which missions in Borderlands 2 are both repeatable and give gear as a reward?

Tags: borderlands-2

As far as I can tell, the only mission that is both repeatable (without resetting UVHM) that also gives gear as a mission reward is the [final round](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Magic_Slaughter:_Badass_Round) of Murderlin's Magic Slaughter missions which gives you a purple gun as the reward.

Is that the only one, or are there others that do so?

Comment: I'm using the mission to inflate my backpack to larger than it's intended to go, [see here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/350566/is-there-a-maximum-size-to-the-inventory-in-borderlands-2) for why, and I'm hoping there was a mission that I forgot about/missed that gives something other than a gun as the reward.  I'm also just generally curious as to whether it's the only mission like it in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went and scraped all the missions listed on the [Borderlands Wiki page](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Borderlands_2_mission_flow), and by my reckoning, there are 139 missions that provide an item as a reward, and 120 of those provide non-skin/head gear.

Of the missions in that list, there are **2** that I know to be repeatable:

- Magic Slaughter: Badass Round
- More History of Simulated Violence

Both provide a purple weapon as a reward.  There do not seem to be **any** missions that can be repeated that give any other type of gear.

All of the other repeatable missions give things like Eridium or Torgue Tokens, but no gear.

---

Other things of note:

- There are up to 14 relics as mission rewards
- There are up to 24 shields as mission rewards
- There are up to 19 grenade mods as mission rewards
- There are up to 4 class mods as mission rewards

Some of these rewards are mutually exclusive, however.